# c# clock without timer

Tags: c#, timer, clock

I making a project with C# and serial communication. In my project, I want to take a sample data from microcontroller output string or byte whatever. I want get pc clock (as hour>label1, minute>label2, second>label3 or all of them) in a label without using timer. Every second I want to take a sample from microcontroller. I had gone 2 way.First one: adding timer to windows form and making a clock.After 3 hours later> real time 03:00 hours passed and in my windows from ~02:53 hours passed beacuse of C# read ever code line and time is passing in that time. Secondly I want to read Pc clock and take a sample reference with that clock. Problem is C# pass some seconds (do not take a sample) beacuse of above reason or (??).

I just want to ask and learn from you. Is it possible to update pc time (on label (or others)) info without using Toolbox>timer.

reference code:

```
System.DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()
```

Comment: without using timer???

Comment: And why do you hate using timer?

Comment: If you don't use a timer, what would be the trigger for the update?

Comment: Timer (what I mean) system.windows.forms.timer

Comment: "If you don't use a timer, what would be the trigger for the update?" I dont know, I just want to learn it is possible?

Comment: Ok, I make a small project with Serial communaication. I want to make it real time system. I had gone 2 way.First one: adding timer to windows form  and making a clock.After 3 hours later> real time 03:00 hours passed and in my windows from ~02:53 hours passed beacuse of C# read ever code line and time is passing in that time. Secondly I want to read Pc clock and take a sample reference with that clock. Problem is C# pass some seconds beacuse of above reason.

Comment: @user3722613 That should have been added to your question rather than as a comment.

Comment: If I add a class to my project which is include timer. Is it affect the system work.

Comment: "That should have been added to your question rather than as a comment." May I add now?

Comment: @user3722613 yes, edit the question to include all relevant details!

Answer (score 0):

Within the .Net framework exisiting different timer classes for different purposes. For a first wrap up you should read [Comparing the Timer Classes in the .NET Framework Class Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164015.aspx).

Then you should maybe give [`System.Timers.Timer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx) a try instead of [`System.Windows.Forms.Timer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.aspx).

Comment: Important [link](http://mitch-wheat.blogspot.com.tr/2010/12/comparing-net-timer-classes.html) and [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/167365/All-about-NET-Timers-A-Comparison)